# Do you use rice hulls with your Blichmann False Bottom?

Tags: mashing, lauter, rims, rice-hulls

I used to use a [simple drink cooler and screen](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/gallery/data/1/7346-10_Braid_in_Cooler_r.jpg) for a mash tun, but was given a chugger pump, 10 gallon Blichmann G2, and [false bottom](http://67.222.37.65/media/blichmann/Button_louver_false_bottom.JPG) which I now use in a RIMS setup. The first time I brewed a wheat on the new system I used 1# of rice hulls like I always did, but some of the hulls slipped through the false bottom and clogged my quick disconnects. Has anyone else experienced this?

I brewed the same beer again last week, but left the rice hulls out of the equation and had no issues. I am now wondering if they are even necessary with the Blichmann false bottom.

**EDIT**
Grain Bill:

- 5 lbs. 2-Row Brewer’s Malt
- 4 lb. White Wheat Malt
- 0.5 lb. Flaked Wheat
- 0.25 lb. Munich Malt
- 0.25 lb. Aromatic Malt

In your experience, about what amount of Wheat or Oats will cause stuck mashes or lautering problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually should not need to use rice hulls. If you are keep torrified wheat or oats below 5% you'll be fine. When you go beyond 5% of the malt bill especially with oats I would advise adding some rice hulls, about 1/10 the amount of oats you are using eg for a pound (454g) of oats about 1.5-2oz (50g) of hulls.

This has always worked well for me.

If you still get a stuck mash add extra hulls and give it a good stir, then recirculate until the grain bed reforms, and the wort runs clear.

With the malt bill you have shown above you should not require rice hulls.

Answer (score 1):

Even with RIMS you should do the vorlauf step.... Set the grain bed manually before you start RIMS circulation. This will prevent the initial chunks from getting stuck in the RIMS plumbing.

I prefer stainless braided ring as false bottoms. 
[image]